# How to load comments with ajax (in Jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

this codes will submit the comments in the database but they won't show in page and I have to refresh the page to show them, does anyone know what is wrong with this codes?

the Jquery part is:

```
function submit_comment () {
  var uQuestion = $('textarea#txtinput').val();
  //var page_id has created out of this function and it works proparly
  $.post('lib/userActions.php', {uQuestion: uQuestion, page_id: page_id},
    function (data) {
      if (data == 'success') {
        var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
        $('.append_comment').append(item);
    } else {
        alert(data);
    }
});
}
```

the View part is:

```
<?php while ($q = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_set)) {   ?>
     <div class="append_comment" >
             <img src="upload/thumb/
             <?php if (getImageByUserID($q['user_id']) !== null) {
                 echo getImageByUserID($q['user_id'])['file_name'];
             } else {echo 'Blank-person.png';} ?>"
                  alt="user image" >
             <h3><?php echo $q['uname']; ?></h3>
              <p><?php echo $q['text']; ?></p><
     </div>
 <?php } mysqli_free_result($q_set);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the jquery code.. data doesn't likely == 'success' especially considering you're wrapping in a jquery wrapper as if it was.. say.. an html element.

Remove the data=='success' and it'll likely work.. i think that function only gets called on success anyway.

Comment: sorry, i'm new.. what's with all the dots?

Comment: I deleted the if and else , but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: so what does data object look like in the callback? is your PHP actually returning the comment?

Comment: @BillBrasky Sorry that was an accidental comment.

Comment: yes the php part is fine, when I refresh the page comments will show.

Comment: I mean the new comment

Comment: Right, but in userActions.php what do you return to the user after you add the comment to the database? the word "success"?  you should be either returning an html representation of the new comment, or building the object client side.

Comment: once again the php part is completely fine. when the comment submit the show function in php will called with a successful message and they all works fine, if I don't use ajax.

Comment: if you mean the 'success' word in Jquery, it's a typical value of ajax ======> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp